# How to Select Row in ASP Datagrid on clicking it?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datagrid

whenever i click on any cell on that respective row.I need to be able to select a Row in my asp: Datagrid

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgDocument" SelectionMode="Single" runat="server" Localizable="True" Width="100%" UpdateAfterCallBack="False"   AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="Grid"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="dgproposal_SelectedIndexChanged">
<AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="GridAlternativeItem"></AlternatingItemStyle>
<ItemStyle CssClass="GridItem"></ItemStyle>
<Columns>
<asp:BoundColumn Visible="False" DataField="DOCUMENT_NUMBER" HeaderText="Document Number">
</asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Document Title">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.DOCUMENT_NAME") %>' ID="Label3" NAME="Label3">
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
...
```

Comment: I need it to work for onlick.

Answer (score 0):

Use SelectedItemStyle to define the selected record.

```
 <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="Yellow">
         </SelectedItemStyle>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.selecteditemstyle(v=vs.110).aspx